# Any testing tool or framework supporting multiple RPC protocol to test different component

Tags: unit-testing, testing, rpc, web-api-testing, system-design

I just wanted to know whether there is any testing tool or framework (Open-source preferred) available to test multiple type of APIs of component or module.

[image]

In case there is no such things currently available, if someone can suggest how to address this problem (Design)?

Hope I am clear!

Answer (score 3):

It is not a framework but you could try out [soapui](https://www.soapui.org/).
If thats not an option, I would say that you need multiple frameworks. For example [RestAssured](http://rest-assured.io/) to test REST API's.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My question is then if I go with soapui, can I extend it to support other rpc protocols like grpc or rmi or google flat buffers? Currently As I can see it only support REST and SOAP.

Comment: I am not sure if it is the best way but you can use groovy scripts in soapUI. You can probably achieve other protocols with that.
If not you could extend soapUI with jar files see: https://www.soapui.org/extension-plugins/old-style-extensions/developing-old-style-extensions.html

Comment: My vote is for RestAssured, makes it dead simple to hit most any API.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a maintainer of [an open-source API Testing tool](https://github.com/LinuxSuRen/api-testing/) that was released with the MIT license. It provides the HTTP and gRPC support.